# Reading a json response in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

i am trying to reading json  response from server by using jquery in webpage, this is my json response `{"code":0,"message":success"}`, and this is my jquery code . this code does not sent data to server and does not read json response from server. please help me to resolve the problem.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event) {

    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();

    /* get some values from elements on the page: */
    var $form = $( this ),
        userid=$form.find(input[name="userid"]).val(),
        file = $form.find( 'input[name="file"]' ).val(),
        filename = $form.find( 'input[name="filename"]' ).val(),
        url = $form.attr( 'action' );

    /* Send the data using post */
    var posting = $.post( url, { userid: userid,file:file,filename:filename } );

    /* Put the results in a div */var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "code": "0" }' );
    $.getJSON(url, { get_param: 'code' }, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            $('body').append($('<div>', {
                text: element.name
            }));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i think `element.name` will be undefined try `element.code` or `element.message`

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error, in the find method quotes is missing :)

```
userid=$form.find(input[name="userid"]).val(),
```

cange to

```
userid=$form.find('input[name="userid"]').val(),
```

PS: All browser have a javascript console, that show u where is script crashed